# Oracle NLS_LANG set properly(WE8ISO8859P1) but sessions starts in US7ASCII

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, oracleclient, nls-lang

On Linux Open SuSE
I have my env variable set properly, meaning NLS_LANG is set to WE8ISO8859P1, and it is all started and exported in ~/.bashrc
However when the system starts and connects to Oracle the session always starts as US7ASCII

What am I missing?

[SQL Developer Connection Status query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkCzA.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the system starts and connects to Oracle'? when you boot the system? when you login? what process is trying to connect?

Comment: When the Oracle Client-Server session is established it is established as a US7ASCII session. See image....

Comment: it would have helped greatly if you had shown the query that generated the result set that you show. Also better to paste directly into your message rather than posting a link. That said, it _appears_ that you are looking at v$session_connect_info. The documentation says that CLIENT_CHARSET is "Client character set as specified in the NLS_LANG environmentvariable or in the OCIEnvNlsCreate() call; "  So it appears your client is overriding your environment variable.

Comment: The `CLIENT_CHARSET` in `V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO` view is not reliable. SQLDeveloper is JDBC/Java based which does not use the `NLS_LANG` variable, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643): *Starting from Oracle Database 10g, the NLS_LANG variable is no longer part of the JDBC globalization mechanism. The JDBC driver does not check NLS environment. So, setting it has no effect.*

Comment: This was the query used the get the result set in image:
`select * from v$session_connect_info where sid = ANY(select sid from v$session where module like '%pcname%');`
@EdStevens why is the client overriding its own environment variable? And what needs to be changed so the client starts with the charset as set in environment variable?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit SQL Developer was only used to read the status out of the database. The client ist using Oracle instant client to connect to the database, but it's overrriding/not using the set environment variables.

Comment: What is the exact value of NLS_LANG?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `NLS_LANG=german_austria.WE8ISO8859P1`

Comment: What do you mean by "*when the system starts and connects to Oracle*"? What is the application which connects to Oracle?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit when the system which has the Oracle Client(oracle instant client 12) installed starts and connects to the database, it always connects with the wrong client_charset, even though the environment variable(on the client system) is set correctly.

Comment: You still did not tell us what is you client app. Is it running on the system you're configuring with .bashrc? Do you connect manually or is it a job started by cron or something like that?

Comment: Again, what is  "the system"?

Comment: Why do you think your client runs on `US7ASCII`? As I wrote the `CLIENT_CHARSET` column is useless. Do you have any problem with special characters?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes exactly, some special characters are being lost when being written into the database which makes me believe that the client is actually running the `US7ASCII` `CLIENT_CHARSET`
There are actually 16 different systems connecting to the database, and all are shown "correctly" in the `CLIENT_CHARSET` entry, which makes me to believe that the column has the right information.